# AWS Linux2 Apache2 PHP-FPM mod_fcgi Timeout

Tags: php, linux, timeout, apache2, fastcgi

Upfront, Any help is appreciated. I have spent over a week 8 hours a day trying different configuration settings, spinning up new servers to test on and still get the same time out issue.

The set up Apache 2.4.54 (mpm event), PHP 5.4.16 (using PHP-FPM not mod_php) with mod_fcgid on AWS Linux 2. I have set up test server to try this on as to not jack up the production server.

Installed with yum install php-cli php-common php-fpm php-mbstring php-mcrypt  php-mysqlnd php-pdo php-pear php-process php-xml mod_fcgid httpd

I have read probably over 100 install, troubleshooting articles from all over the Internet and tried them as well. I think it's probably something simple that I am missing but hoping someone on here can help. Boss is getting irritated so any direction is appreciated.

When I go to the test page t.php (code below) it will run for 50 seconds and then just stop. I have also tried php code to run an exec command to run another php script for 60, 90, 300 seconds with sleep function and it does the same thing but the code executed in exec still runs for the correct amount of time in the background. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

I have tried it using socket for php-fpm and the standard 127.0.0.1:9000 with same results.

Now to the config data.

/etc/php.ini

Only changes made to php.ini everything else is standard settings.

```
default_socket_timeout = 600
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 256M
```

==============================

/etc/php-fpm.conf

No changes for these settings.

==============================

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

No changes to httpd.conf except added to bottom

```
TimeOut 600
ProxyTimeout 600
```

============================

/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

```
# Documentation is available at
# http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

# Use FastCGI to process .fcg .fcgi & .fpl scripts
AddHandler  fcgid-script fcgi php fpl
FcgidConnectTimeout 600
FcgidMaxRequestLen 268435456
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 10
FcgidIOTimeout 600


# Sane place to put sockets and shared memory file
FcgidIPCDir /run/mod_fcgid
FcgidProcessTableFile /run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm
```

============================

/etc/httpd/conf.d/mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        AddHandler cgi-script .pl
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

        AddType application/x-shockwave-flash   swf
        AddType image/gif .gif
        AddType image/jpg .jpg

        LimitRequestBody 0

        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                #LogLevel debug
        </Directory>

       SuexecUserGroup apache apache

       <Proxy "unix:/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1">
               ProxySet disablereuse=off
                ProxySet connectiontimeout=600 
                ProxySet timeout=600
        </Proxy>

       <FilesMatch \.php$>
               AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
               SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1
       </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

================================

/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-fcgid.conf

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidConnectTimeout 600
  AddType  application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
  Alias /php-fcgi /usr/bin/php-fcgi
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

================================

/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
listen = /run/php-fpm/example.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

user = apache
group = apache
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
request_terminate_timeout = 0
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 600
php_admin_value[max_input_time] = 600
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session
```

=====================================

httpd -V output

```
[root@ip-ipaddress etc]# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.54 ()
Server built:   Jun 30 2022 11:02:23
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:124
Server loaded:  APR 1.7.0, APR-UTIL 1.6.1, PCRE 8.32 2012-11-30
Compiled using: APR 1.7.0, APR-UTIL 1.6.1, PCRE 8.32 2012-11-30
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_PROC_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

=====================================

phpinfo()

```
PHP Version => 5.4.16

System => Linux ip-ipaddress.ec2.internal 5.10.130-118.517.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 13 16:51:52 UTC 2022 x86_64
Build Date => Oct 31 2019 18:33:21
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqlnd_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqlnd_mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/posix.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php.d/wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini

PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 5.4.16

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
exit_on_timeout => Off => Off
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 256M => 256M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 16K => 16K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.79.1
Age => 9
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => No
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
Largefile => Yes
NTLM => Yes
SPNEGO => Yes
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
krb4 => No
libz => Yes
CharConv => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, gophers, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, mqtt, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-koji-linux-gnu
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
ZLib Version => 1.2.7
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.3

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => UTC

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.9.1
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

ereg

Regex Library => Bundled library enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 1.4 $Id$
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
version => 1.0.5

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Id: 2aa8dd57d9c0c655cd45e6e5872bb95fa5ad76cf $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

gmp

gmp support => enabled
GMP version => 6.0.0

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5 

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.26

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version => 20901
libXML streams => enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
libmbfl version => 1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check => On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 4.7.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

mhash

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off

mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off

mysqlnd

mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $
Compression => supported
SSL => supported
Command buffer size => 4096
Read buffer size => 32768
Read timeout => 31536000
Collecting statistics => Yes
Collecting memory statistics => No
Tracing => n/a
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,example,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password
API Extensions => mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql

mysqlnd statistics =>  
bytes_sent => 0
bytes_received => 0
packets_sent => 0
packets_received => 0
protocol_overhead_in => 0
protocol_overhead_out => 0
bytes_received_ok_packet => 0
bytes_received_eof_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_header_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_field_meta_packet => 0
bytes_received_rset_row_packet => 0
bytes_received_prepare_response_packet => 0
bytes_received_change_user_packet => 0
packets_sent_command => 0
packets_received_ok => 0
packets_received_eof => 0
packets_received_rset_header => 0
packets_received_rset_field_meta => 0
packets_received_rset_row => 0
packets_received_prepare_response => 0
packets_received_change_user => 0
result_set_queries => 0
non_result_set_queries => 0
no_index_used => 0
bad_index_used => 0
slow_queries => 0
buffered_sets => 0
unbuffered_sets => 0
ps_buffered_sets => 0
ps_unbuffered_sets => 0
flushed_normal_sets => 0
flushed_ps_sets => 0
ps_prepared_never_executed => 0
ps_prepared_once_executed => 0
rows_fetched_from_server_normal => 0
rows_fetched_from_server_ps => 0
rows_buffered_from_client_normal => 0
rows_buffered_from_client_ps => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_buffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_normal_unbuffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_buffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_unbuffered => 0
rows_fetched_from_client_ps_cursor => 0
rows_affected_normal => 0
rows_affected_ps => 0
rows_skipped_normal => 0
rows_skipped_ps => 0
copy_on_write_saved => 0
copy_on_write_performed => 0
command_buffer_too_small => 0
connect_success => 0
connect_failure => 0
connection_reused => 0
reconnect => 0
pconnect_success => 0
active_connections => 0
active_persistent_connections => 0
explicit_close => 0
implicit_close => 0
disconnect_close => 0
in_middle_of_command_close => 0
explicit_free_result => 0
implicit_free_result => 0
explicit_stmt_close => 0
implicit_stmt_close => 0
mem_emalloc_count => 0
mem_emalloc_amount => 0
mem_ecalloc_count => 0
mem_ecalloc_amount => 0
mem_erealloc_count => 0
mem_erealloc_amount => 0
mem_efree_count => 0
mem_efree_amount => 0
mem_malloc_count => 0
mem_malloc_amount => 0
mem_calloc_count => 0
mem_calloc_amount => 0
mem_realloc_count => 0
mem_realloc_amount => 0
mem_free_count => 0
mem_free_amount => 0
mem_estrndup_count => 0
mem_strndup_count => 0
mem_estndup_count => 0
mem_strdup_count => 0
proto_text_fetched_null => 0
proto_text_fetched_bit => 0
proto_text_fetched_tinyint => 0
proto_text_fetched_short => 0
proto_text_fetched_int24 => 0
proto_text_fetched_int => 0
proto_text_fetched_bigint => 0
proto_text_fetched_decimal => 0
proto_text_fetched_float => 0
proto_text_fetched_double => 0
proto_text_fetched_date => 0
proto_text_fetched_year => 0
proto_text_fetched_time => 0
proto_text_fetched_datetime => 0
proto_text_fetched_timestamp => 0
proto_text_fetched_string => 0
proto_text_fetched_blob => 0
proto_text_fetched_enum => 0
proto_text_fetched_set => 0
proto_text_fetched_geometry => 0
proto_text_fetched_other => 0
proto_binary_fetched_null => 0
proto_binary_fetched_bit => 0
proto_binary_fetched_tinyint => 0
proto_binary_fetched_short => 0
proto_binary_fetched_int24 => 0
proto_binary_fetched_int => 0
proto_binary_fetched_bigint => 0
proto_binary_fetched_decimal => 0
proto_binary_fetched_float => 0
proto_binary_fetched_double => 0
proto_binary_fetched_date => 0
proto_binary_fetched_year => 0
proto_binary_fetched_time => 0
proto_binary_fetched_datetime => 0
proto_binary_fetched_timestamp => 0
proto_binary_fetched_string => 0
proto_binary_fetched_blob => 0
proto_binary_fetched_enum => 0
proto_binary_fetched_set => 0
proto_binary_fetched_geometry => 0
proto_binary_fetched_other => 0
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_quit => 0
com_init_db => 0
com_query => 0
com_field_list => 0
com_create_db => 0
com_drop_db => 0
com_refresh => 0
com_shutdown => 0
com_statistics => 0
com_process_info => 0
com_connect => 0
com_process_kill => 0
com_debug => 0
com_ping => 0
com_time => 0
com_delayed_insert => 0
com_change_user => 0
com_binlog_dump => 0
com_table_dump => 0
com_connect_out => 0
com_register_slave => 0
com_stmt_prepare => 0
com_stmt_execute => 0
com_stmt_send_long_data => 0
com_stmt_close => 0
com_stmt_reset => 0
com_stmt_set_option => 0
com_stmt_fetch => 0
com_deamon => 0
bytes_received_real_data_normal => 0
bytes_received_real_data_ps => 0

example statistics =>  
stat1 => 0
stat2 => 0

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.32 2012-11-30

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.7.17

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.1
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Id: c5042cc34acebcc0926625b57dff03deebbe6472 $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => enabled
Native OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

Revision => $Id: 32db6705f5b617967a546be3114e178a4138c1ca $

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \> 

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: 6c4d8062369898a397e4b128348042f5c01b4427 $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user 
Registered serializer handlers => php php_binary wddx 

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.entropy_file => /dev/urandom => /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length => 32 => 32
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.hash_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.hash_function => 0 => 0
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

shmop

shmop support => enabled

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: 692516840b2d7d6e7aedb0bedded1f53b764a99f $
Schema support => enabled

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 0.7
SQLite Library => 3.7.17

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 600 => 600
from => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

sysvmsg

sysvmsg support => enabled
Revision => $Id: e268047b695fe9a43cdf415c429729252347becd $

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

wddx

WDDX Support => enabled
WDDX Session Serializer => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.1

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

xsl

XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.28
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.9.1
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 1.1.28

zip

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id: 0c033d4e4613d577409950ed7bf8da4b68286d15 $
Zip version => 1.11.0
Compiled against libzip version => 0.10.1

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.7
Linked Version => 1.2.7

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm

Had to remove some of the irrelevent data due to posting character limits.
```

=================================

/var/log/httpd/error_log

```
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933420 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933463 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] mod_authz_core.c(818): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933506 2022] [proxy:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] mod_proxy.c(1505): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933513 2022] [proxy_ajp:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] mod_proxy_ajp.c(769): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH00894: declining URL fcgi://127.0.0.1/var/www/html/t.php
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933528 2022] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1056): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH01076: url: fcgi://127.0.0.1/var/www/html/t.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933533 2022] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1063): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://127.0.0.1/var/www/html/t.php
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933541 2022] [proxy:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] proxy_util.c(2597): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH00944: connecting fcgi://127.0.0.1/var/www/html/t.php to 127.0.0.1:8000
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933545 2022] [proxy:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] proxy_util.c(2634): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH02545: fcgi: has determined UDS as /run/php-fpm/latino.sock
[Thu Sep 01 18:54:11.933549 2022] [proxy:debug] [pid 7743:tid 140180498913024] proxy_util.c(2820): [client 111.111.111.111:29476] AH00947: connected /var/www/html/t.php to httpd-UDS:0
```

================================

/var/www/html/t.php

```
<?php
echo "Going to sleep for 60s\n";
sleep(60);
echo "I'm awake now.\n";
?>
```

================================

/var/www/html/t1.php

```
<?php
exec('/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/t2.php', $output, $result);
print_r($output);
print_r($result);
?>
```

/var/www/html/t2.php

```
<?php
echo "Going to sleep for 60s\n";
sleep(60);
echo "I'm awake now.\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After more research and testing I was still getting the same results of a timeout after 50 seconds. I set up another test server with Apache and mod_php with

```
php.ini
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
```

and

```
httpd.conf
TimeOut 600
```

Basic Apache/PHP install and still had the same issue, timeout at 50 seconds. I installed lynx on the local server and tried the URL. Bam, it worked. Installed lynx on my development computer and still got the timeout issue. And for the fun of it I tried it on my cell phone and got back the correct response.

I am assuming it has something to do with the service provider. For home I am using a cellular modem with ATT data. My phone is TMobile and a co-working said it was working fine until the other day and they started noticing the timeout issue. Not sure what they are using at home but their phone that they use as a hotspot on occasion is Sprint.

Ran the tests, restarted modem several times and made sure I was getting good speeds, ATT 25Mb, TMobile 18Mb.

I ran a test on the production server from my phone and it worked as well so I am marking this as resolved as it is not an issue with configuration settings.